# Cannot install design-time package: missing @Classes@TStream@Write$qqrpxvi from vcl50.bpl

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

## Short Version

- My *design-time* package cannot install
- because my *run-time* package library bpl
- requires the export `@Classes@TStream@Write$qqrpxvi` from `vcl50.bpl`
- that does not exist

## Long Version

When trying to install a *design-time* package, Delphi 5 gets a loader error:

[image]

> The procedure entry point @Classes@TStream@Write$qqrpxvi could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\program files (x86)\borland\delphi5\Projects\Bpl\AvatarDateTimePickerD5.bpl.

Once you clear the error dialog shown by the loader, Delphi shows it's own version of the same error:

[image]

### So i check the file

I use **Depends** to check the exports in the dll:

```
c:\program files (x86)\borland\delphi5\Projects\Bpl\AvatarDateTimePickerD5.bpl
```

And sure enough, there is **no** export named:

```
@Classes@TStream@Write@qqrpxvi
```

In fact, there's no export that starts with **@Classes** ***at all***:

[image]

### Make sure it's loading the right one

So i use **Process Monitor** to make sure it's reading the correct file. And it is:

[image]

### So check the runtime build

You'll remember there's usually two packages:

- **ContosoGrobberD5**: *run-time*
- **ContosoGrobberD5D**: *design-time*

In this case it's the *design-time* package that's loading it's dependancy on the *run-time* package:

> AvatarDateTimePicker**D5**.bpl

So i'll load up that earlier-generated *run-time* package to watch it build, and it builds without incident:

[image]

and it writes to the expected location. And it does all it's file write operations:

[image]

[image]

It's successfully, correctly, and quite intentionally, not generating a DLL export named:

```
@Classes@TStream@Write@qqrpxvi
```

But the corresponding *design-time* package claims it needs such an import.

## Depends says not quite

If i run **Depends** on the *design-time* bpl, i see the failed chain:

- **AvatarDateTimePickerD5D.bpl** *(design-time dll)*

  - **AvatarDateTimePickerD5.bpl** *(run-time dll)*
  - **vcl50.bpl**

    - **Missing Export**: `@Classes@TStream@Read$qqrpvi`
    - **Missing Export**: `@Classes@TStream@Write$qqrpxvi`

[image]

So apparently it's **`vcl50.bpl`** that's missing the export

### Check vcl50.bpl for export @Classes@TStream@Write

So i monitor the operation to **Install** the *design-time* package, and after some hunting around, it finds it in the path:

[image]

In the *"`System32`"* folder:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcl50.bpl

So i check the exports of `vcl50.bpl`. And it's right, there is no export `@Classes@TStream@Write$______`:

[image]

And it *looks* like the file:

[image]

**Created**: 1/24/2000 4:01 am
**SHA-1**: `29398F5CD966335EB38377962B12780DDEA9DBDC`

So what's going on?

Comment: @MartynA It's just name mangling

Comment: This sometimes happens when you have a mismatched .DCU file that the linker finds instead of the correct one. It's usually solved by doing a search for all instances of the .dcu and renaming or deleting them, and then doing a build. In this case, I'd start by searching your drive for all of the .dcus related to both of your packages (anything that is from your own source files) - not just the folders you're aware of, but your entire drive.

Comment: **UltraSearch** (my new favorite tool) is able to make quick work of finding all 142 versions of the `dcu` *(it scans the NTFS database directly)*, and deleting them. Paradoxically i can Build the runtime-only package, but i get the same error if try **Install** the runtime-only package (rather than the error saying this is a runtime-only package and cannot be installed)

Comment: `TStream.Read()` and `TStream.Write()` are abstract methods, they have no implementations in `TStream` itself, so it makes sense that there would be no BPL exports for them.  Nothing should be trying to import those methods directly. So your runtime package is faulty in that required. As to why it is doing that, I have no idea.

Comment: Your `AvatarDateTimePickerD5.bpl` runtime package (or any package at all, actually) should include rtl.dcp in its `requires` clause. (That's where `Classes` unit is exported.)

Comment: @Ian: Everything (voidtools.com) does the same. Has been one of my favourite tools since the beginning of time. <g>

Comment: Lots of pictures, but no code (great cry and little wool). @Ondrej is very likely right. Remove the pics and show us the code of `AvatarDateTimePickerD5.dpk`.

Comment: Can you envision any code that could cause that? Unfortunately it includes 7 other units. The point is that there's no way i would have requested such an export;it's the VCL/RTL/BPL. What *would* cause it? Yes, if i start over with an empty package it does not confuse Delphi. Also, everything after the title is *"research effort"*. Would it be helpful if you had the other 4 packages and 120 units that make up my install so you can test it on your Delphi 5?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I remember trying Everything. I remember it wanted to try to create it's own database, rather than just search. And now i remember that it just....[won't show me anything](https://imgur.com/a/llJudjW). I'm sure there's some good reason why it doesn't show anything. But there's something satisfying about UltraSearch [being able to search my entire system, instantly, without having to create an index, or crawl every folder](https://i.imgur.com/fLsxEBV.png)

Comment: Everything doesn't have to crawl anything either. For me, it works instantaneously. It uses the NTFS database too. Only the first time, it had a delay of a few seconds to build the database. It even reflects changes to the file system immediately. I have no idea why it doesn't work for you.